# best way to add a spring boot web application with JSPs to a docker container?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

so i have a spring boot web application, it uses JSPs, and im supposed to put it in a container .
my question is what is the best way ?
ive tried to copy the project and then run it there using a wmvn like so :
dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD . /input-webapp
WORKDIR /input-webapp
EXPOSE 8080:8080
ENTRYPOINT ./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

which works, but it takes a long time getting the dependencies and feels messy .

and ive tried to package it into a jar, and then copy the jar only, and run it :
dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD target/input-webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar input-webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080:8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","input-webapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

but this way it cant see the JSPs, or at least i think this is the problem, as i get a 404.

so is there a better way ? can i copy the jsps plus the jar to make it work?
thanks

Comment: [This might help](https://docs.docker.com/language/java/build-images/)

Comment: it does a bit, but i still need to know about doing it in a jar ? is there a way to make it access the jsps?